# Is there a way to alternate Pistons from one switch/lever

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm creating a set of doors that are opened and closed by one switch. but I want to have one door open and the other closed from one lever. 
Is there a way where door one can be open while door two is closed if they are run off the same lever, if so please share and explain cause I'm lost in trying to create this system, and I'd love to include it in my house.

Answer (score 3):

This is very simple to do using a signal reverser, which is simply a block with a redstone torch on the end. Place the reverser somewhere in the line of redstone to one of the doors, but not the other. Here is a visual representation.

[image: redstone]

Answer (score 1):

Yes have one door open and the other closed and hit a switch connected by
redstone and hit the switch to make that happen.

Comment: This is a very good method. They'll both internally be the same openness, but will physically be in different positions. +1.